# Does the Big Bang have the absolute lowest amount of entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, entropy, universe, big-bang

We know that the event of the Big Bang has low entropy (and we don't know why), but... do we know for certain (or through convincing mathematical evidence) that the event of the Big Bang indeed has the lowest amount of entropy possible? To me, it seems that if that's true, then there is only one way the Big Bang could be ordered, and thus, only one version of the Big Bang could occur.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/154307/

Comment: Thank you. Although it's not an exact duplicate, it does answer my question to some extent. I was just curious if entropy was at an absolute minimum at the Big Bang.